# Custom adapter with buttons memory

Tags: android, memory, button, adapter

I am currently using this code for the listeners of my buttons to do something :

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = convertView;
     if (v == null) {
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
     }
     Person p = persons.get(position);
     if (p != null) {

         Button but = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
         but.setText(p.getDescription());
         but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do stuff
            }
        });


     }
     return v;
 }
```

Now I wonder , Is this good for memory management or is it better to do a onListItemClick in the activity itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I wonder , Is this good for memory management

It could be better.  Because a list gets scrolled and these items are re-used, you will end up creating a lot of `OnClickListener` objects and orphaning others.  It's not a memory leak necessarily because the old ones will be collected, but it's still not a great choice.

> or is it better to do a onListItemClick in the activity itself?

If you can get away with it because you there is only one click action for an item in the list, you should absolutely stick to `OnItemClickListener` for the list and not handle this yourself.

However, if you need to create specific portions of each item to be clickable or want more than one action to be performed for a given item, it would be best if possible to collect those actions into a single `OnClickListener` that is created once and then attached to each item in `getView()`.  You can differentiate which item was clicked by attaching metadata about the click action and maybe list position to the views themselves with `setTag()`.  If this logic is complex, it may be best to create a custom view for your list items, and let the view itself handle all the clicks for each row rather than attempting to handles these actions externally.